# How can i search for keywords in a javascript array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a search input component in a React project. I have an array of objects that I am mapping over when someone clicks search. The goal is to take the user input and use it to find something similar in the array. Right now I have to search the exact item for it to work. For example if I search "used car for sale" it will show that object but if I remove any words/letters it will not. Is there any way to only look for a keyword? Thank you!

```
function Search() {
  const items = [
    {
      title: "Used Car for sale",
      description: "I am selling a used 2003 Honda Civic. Works well.",
      price: "$1000",
    },
    {
      title: "computer for sale",
      description: "Selling a brand new Dell computer",
      price: "$800",
    },
    {
      title: "Used phone for sale",
      description: "I am selling my iphone 1",
      price: "$400",
    },
  ];

 
  const [text, setText] = useState("");

 

  const searchPosts = () => {
    items.map((item) => {
      if (item.title === text) {
        console.log(item);
      } else {
        console.log("item not found");
      }
    });
  };
  return (
    <>
      <h1>{posts[0].title}</h1>
      <div className="input-group mb-3 main-search">
        <input
          type="text"
          className="form-control "
          placeholder="Search for anything..."
          aria-label="Recipient's username"
          aria-describedby="button-addon2"
          onChange={(e) => setText(e.target.value)}
        />
        <div className="input-group-append">
          <button
            onClick={searchPosts}
            className="btn btn-outline-secondary main-search-button"
            type="button"
            id="button-addon2"
          >
            Search
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: `.find()`/`.filter()`/`.includes()`... does that ring the bell for you?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), and read up on [asking good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). After doing some research and searching for related topics on SO, try it yourself. If you're stuck, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt note exactly where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

You can split your words in the title field and check against the keyword you provide

In the first example 2 records are returned since inside the keyword string both words are contained within the records

In the second, all records are returned since sale is present in all elements

```js
const items = [{
      title: "Used Car for sale",
      description: "I am selling a used 2003 Honda Civic. Works well.",
      price: "$1000",
    },
    {
      title: "computer for sale",
      description: "Selling a brand new Dell computer",
      price: "$800",
    },
    {
      title: "Used phone for sale",
      description: "I am selling my iphone 1",
      price: "$400",
    },
  ];


  function filterResults(list, keyword) {
    return list.filter(x => {
      const arr = x.title.toLowerCase().split(' ');
      return arr.some(y => keyword.toLowerCase().includes(y))

    });
  }

  console.log(filterResults(items, 'computer phone'))
  console.log(filterResults(items, 'computer'))
```